# How to parse this web page (and convert into a dictionary) in Python

Tags: python, parsing, search, mapping, html-parsing

I want to fetch some data from a certain web page (online book store).

The web pages look like this: http://www.rob389.com/dp/tr/11/9789754681383

I want to parse the `<script>` section that contains the following string:

```
tOBJ.DATA[0].MMM00_ITEM_CODE="9789754681383"
```

Where *9789754681383* is the ISBN number.

I first need to find and extract the correct `<script>` section.

Then, I want to iterate through the content of the **tOBJ.DATA[0]** object and convert it into a dictionary which would look like:

```
my_dict["MMM00_ITEM_CODE"] = "9789754681383"
my_dict["MMM00_TITLE"] = "Uykusuz Bir Gece"
```

And so on...

I guess it's possible to do it with python with few number of lines, but I cannot figure out.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Any other parsing suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This sure would be a lot easier with a proper API.

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't see any way of getting the XML data out.

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup. Easy to use selectors for the data you are trying to pull.

Comment: @nathancahill The data I'm trying to parse is not XML-structured. So, to me, it looks like I'll need to do a lot of string searching. And I'm not sure Beautiful Soup could find the section I'm looking for easier that any simple string search. As far as I understand, Beautiful Soup works "beautifully" with XML-like structures?

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, after looking at the data, string searching is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would almost always recommend the use of BeautifulSoup - however, this page seems to have a '<!-->' tag half-way down which kills the parser. So, `re` to the rescue...

```
import urllib
import re

url = 'http://www.rob389.com/dp/tr/11/9789754681383'
txt = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
pat = re.compile(r'tOBJ\.DATA\[0\]\.(\w+)\s*=\s*([^;]*);', flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)
my_dict = dict((k,v.strip('"')) for k,v in pat.findall(txt))
```

which results in a 132-entry dictionary including

```
'MMM00_ITEM_CODE': '9789751028440',
'MMM00_ORG_TITLE': '026512',
'MMM00_SRC_CODE': '9789754681383',
'MMM00_TITLE': 'Uykusuz Bir Gece',
'MMM00_TYPE': 'M',
'MMM00_WEIGHT': '0',
'MMM00_WIDTH': '13.6',
```

If you want to restrict it to only keys beginning with 'MMM00', try

```
my_dict = dict((k,v.strip('"')) for k,v in pat.findall(txt) if k.startswith('MMM00'))
```

which only returns 15 items.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for! There are two answers, and I picked the earlier one as the answer. But this is what I meant by "I guess it's possible to do it with python with few number of lines".

Comment: I also had to cut the page from "<td id=SCOL23" on to avoid overwriting the existing (and important) keys.

Comment: I would suggest incorporating the removal of extra `"`s to the regular expression - as well as matching only the keys starting with `MMM00` if you go for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and a little bit of code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlsplit

def isbnExtractor(url):

    urlContent = url.strip('/').split('/')
    print urlContent[6]
```

And this should do the trick. Like this:

```
PS python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from parse import isbnExtractor
>>> url = "http://www.rob389.com/dp/tr/11/9789754681383"
>>> isbnExtractor(url)
9789754681383
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this answers my question. I'm trying to parse the **content** of a web page.

Answer (score 1):

The page is so horribly invalid XML that all the normal approaches using `parse()` from `lxml.tree` followed by `xpath` etc fail miserably. So looks like your best bet is something like:

```
>>> import re
>>> import urllib
>>> import pprint
>>> s = urllib.urlopen("http://www.rob389.com/dp/tr/11/9789754681383").read()
>>> magic = re.compile(r'tOBJ.DATA\[0\].([A-Z0-9_]+)="([^"]+)"')
>>> my_dict = dict(magic.findall(s))
>>> pprint.pprint(my_dict)
{'DISC_PERC': '15.0000000000',
 'EXCHANGE_RT': '2.2815',
 'LNK_PREFIX': 'uykusuz-bir-gece-jill-murphy',
 'LST_PRICE': '7.500000000000000',
 'LST_YAX02_CODE': 'YTL',
 'MMG00_CODE': '11',
 'MMG00_TITLE': 'Kitap',
 'MMM00_DESC': '...<br />Cad\xfdlar Okulu M\xfcd\xfcr\xfc, \\',
 'MMM00_DESC250': '...<br />Cad\xfdlar Okulu M\xfcd\xfcr\xfc, \\',
 'MMM00_DISC_PERC_SAL': '25',
 'MMM00_HEIGHT': '19.6',
 'MMM00_ITEM_CODE': '9789751028440',
 'MMM00_ORG_TITLE': '026512',
 'MMM00_SRC_CODE': '9789754681383',
 'MMM00_TITLE': 'Uykusuz Bir Gece',
 'MMM00_TYPE': 'M',
 'MMM00_WEIGHT': '0',
 'MMM00_WIDTH': '13.6',
 'MMM00_ZHEIGHT': '1',
 'MMS03_PRICE_1': '7.500000000000000',
 'MMS03_PRICE_2': '0.000000000000000',
 'MMS03_PRICE_3': '7.500000000000000',
 'MMS03_YAX02_CODE_1': 'YTL',
 'MMS03_YAX02_CODE_2': 'YTL',
 'MMS03_YAX02_CODE_3': 'YTL',
 'NWS01_DESC': "<BR>New Orleans'da do\xf0an Lillian Hellman'\xfdn ilkgen\xe7li\xf0i daha sonra oyunlar\xfdnda \xfcst\xfc kapal\xfd olarak yer bulacak olan tuhaf ve h\xfdrsl\xfd akrabalar aras\xfdnda ge\xe7ti. New Orleans ve New York aras\xfdnda mekik dokuyarak ge\xe7en y\xfdllarda etraf\xfdndaki farkl\xfd k\xfclt\xfcrleri g\xf6zlemleme \xfeans\xfd buldu. Liseyi bitirdikten sonra Columbia ve New York \xdcniversitesi'ne devam ettiyse de, e\xf0itimini yar\xfdda b\xfdrakarak bir yay\xfdnevinde \xe7al\xfd\xfemaya ba\xfelad\xfd. 1920'lerin bohem hayat\xfdna g\xf6z k\xfdrpt\xfd\xf0\xfd bu d\xf6nemde tan\xfd\xfet\xfd\xf0\xfd gen\xe7 yazar Arthur Kober ile evlenerek Hollywood'a ta\xfe\xfdnd\xfd. <BR><BR>1930'lar\xfdn ba\xfe\xfdnda MGM'de d\xfczeltmenlik yapt\xfd. Hevesli bir solcu oldu\xf0u bu y\xfdllarda, i\xfe arkada\xfelar\xfdn\xfd sendikala\xfemalar\xfd i\xe7in<A class=A2 href=\\",
 'NWS01_DESC400': '<A class=A3 href=\\',
 'NWS01_ID': '588',
 'NWS01_IMAGE': '/UD_OBJS/IMAGES/NWS/HSTTR/Hellman_L_231204_365_1.jpg',
 'ON_ESHOP': 'T',
 'PEP01_ID': '229016',
 'PEP01_NAME': 'Jill Murphy',
 'PRD_FNM01_ID': '23462',
 'PRD_FNM01_TITLE': 'Mandolin',
 'PRD_FNM01_TRD_TITLE': 'Say Yay\xfdnlar\xfd',
 'PUR_VAT_VALUE': '8',
 'SAL_PRICE': '6.3750000000',
 'SAL_VAT_VALUE': '8',
 'SAL_YAX02_CODE': 'YTL',
 'UD_10': '~410~|',
 'UD_10_VAL': 'T\xfcrk\xe7e',
 'UD_11': '~1000~|~803.2~|',
 'UD_11_VAL': '\xc7ocuk,\xd6yk\xfc',
 'UD_12': '~1000.4080~|',
 'UD_12_VAL': '\xc7ocuk | 07-12 Ya\xfe | Edebiyat',
 'UD_15': '978-975-468-138-3',
 'UD_15_VAL': '978-975-468-138-3',
 'UD_16': '~PB~|',
 'UD_16_VAL': 'Karton Kapak',
 'UD_19': '01/01/2010',
 'UD_19_VAL': '01/01/2004',
 'UD_2': 'The Worst Witch Strikes Again',
 'UD_20': '92',
 'UD_20_VAL': '92',
 'UD_21': '52',
 'UD_21_VAL': '52',
 'UD_22': '3',
 'UD_22_VAL': '3',
 'UD_23': '1',
 'UD_23_VAL': '1',
 'UD_24': '~HM1~|',
 'UD_24_VAL': '1. Hamur',
 'UD_26': '7-12',
 'UD_26_VAL': '07-12',
 'UD_2_VAL': 'The Worst Witch Strikes Again',
 'UD_3': '~229016~|',
 'UD_30': '1',
 'UD_30_VAL': '1',
 'UD_31': '1',
 'UD_31_VAL': '1',
 'UD_34': '~1~|',
 'UD_34_VAL': '1-3 G\xfcn',
 'UD_36': '1',
 'UD_36_VAL': '1',
 'UD_39': 'VAR',
 'UD_39_VAL': 'Var',
 'UD_3_VAL': 'Jill Murphy',
 'UD_42': '~410~|',
 'UD_42_VAL': 'T\xfcrk\xe7e',
 'UD_6': '~239986~|',
 'UD_6_VAL': 'Seza Sunar',
 'YAX02_CODE': 'EUR'}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I picked the earlier one (I guess it's fair), but needless to say that this one also answers the question.